# how to configure stl-view in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have created a new file .gdbinit on my $HOME directory. and when I am execution gdb command I am getting following error.

```
bld05 abc /users/abc 25 > gdb
GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.3.0.0-1.132.EL4rh)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"./users/abc/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "TL".  Try "help".
```

I don't know what could have gone wrong. Can anyone tell me?

.gdbinit file contains http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the whole content of the file? I have a suspection you are missing a #   S on the first line. Using vim, a?

Comment: Thanks izomorphius .... That was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gdb 6.3 in 2012 does not make much sense (except on Macs). Get something newer, like 7.5. This will also work better with C++.

Also, to load a program in gdb, use  gdb --args /your/binary arg1 arg2